# Selecting rows on specific level with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
id     | upperId   | title
-------+-----------+---------
1      | 0         | World
2      | 1         | Europe
3      | 1         | Asia
4      | 2         | Germany
5      | 4         | Berlin
...
```

You get the idea:

- World

  - Europe

    - Germany

      - Berlin
  - Asia

    - China

      - Peking
    - Japan

Now, I need an SQL query to select all regions from `region` that are on a specific level, say the third. In this example, that would be Germany, Japan and China. For the second level, it would be both Europe and Asia.

It would be preferable if the query would be flexible for all different levels, and not specific to one level.

Is there an SQL way to do this, or do I need to loop all the regions with PHP or so?

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: Export the query result... please

Comment: @NullVoid sorry, what do you mean? I don't know how to do this, so I'd like to see how to build a query for it.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple "Select title FROM tb1 WHERE upperId=2" work?

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. I need all rows on that level. I updated the example. So not only the rows beneath Europe, but also those beneath Asia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for a specific level (in this case third level) you can do:

```
select l3.*
from region l1, region l2, region l3
where l1.upperId = 0
and l2.upperId = l1.id
and l3.upperId = l2.id
```

Comment: Thanks! You'd get bonus points for something generic (i.e. not specific to third level)! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing you should do is add a "depth" column. The query would be simpler and faster to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking for generic solutions. The point here is that what you are doing is implicitely a recursive search on a tree, and as far as I kown, MySQL has no recursive operations.

Thus, you'll have to use recursion (or equivalent iteration) yourself in your code.

Depending on what's implemented in your project, another solution could be to use a [Nested Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) instead of a 'plain' tree. With a Nested Set data structure, your query would lead you to look for adequate .lft and .grt values. Easy and convenient.

Unfortunately, migrating your table to a NestedSet structure is not straightforward. If your table is populated and in production, I guess coding your loop in PHP might be by far faster...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (not fully tested but I assume it will work)

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','yourpw');
mysql_select_db('db') or die (mysql_error());

$strSQL = "Select title FROM table";  
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]"); 

$i = 0;
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
$i++;

$strSQL1 = "Select title FROM table Where upperId='".$i."'";  
$objQuery1 = mysql_query($strSQL1) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL1."]"); 
$objResult1 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery1);

echo "<br>";
echo $objResult1["title"];
}

?>
```